# JMeter Unique once feature

Tags: jmeter

I want to use Unique once setting in JMeter  as used in load runner for a project.
The data are provided through  a CSV file and are parameterized.

If the script is ran with multiple users then also the data should be unique, meaning one data can be used only once.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Users in JMeter equal Threads so just use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)  to read your CSV

> Sharing mode All threads - (the default) the file is shared between all the threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) plugin, it has `KEEP` option, if you set it to `FALSE` once record is read from the source file it will be removed guaranteeing uniqueness even if you run your tests in [Distributed Mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

You can install HTTP Simple Table Server plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter install HTTP Simple Table Server]

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the solution for "Unique Once Vuser setting in jMeter"

1) Create excel and insert data in excel column wise i.e. horizontally insert all the data.

2) Use below code in place of your unique parameter.

```
${__CSVRead(filePath,${__threadNum})}
```

So it will pick unique data for each thread.

Thread_1 Iteration_1 --- Data from col 1

Thread_1 Iteration_2 --- Data from col 1

Thread_1 Iteration_3 --- Data from col 1

Thread_2 Iteration_1 --- Data from col 2

Thread_2 Iteration_2 --- Data from col 2

Thread_2 Iteration_3 --- Data from col 2

Answer (score 0):

Although every answer works perfectly fine, but just a different way using if control.

CSV Data Set Config settings :

[image: Test Plan as shown in the picture]

if controller validation code : `${__groovy(${__jm__Thread Group__idx} == 0,)}`

In this if controller we keep a JSR223 sampler and in that we can have one or more line of following code : `vars.put("VarName",vars.get("CSV_input"))`

where we replace `VarName` :  with the variable name we want to use in the script and `CSV_input` with the the variable name from CSV Data Set Config input